# Proving that $H$ is a representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Given a map $H:G \to GL(\mathbb{C}G)$ where

> $\mathbb{C}G = \Big\{\displaystyle\sum_{g\in G} a_g \,g : a_g \in \mathbb{C}\Big\}$ is the set of all formal linear combinations of members of the group $G$.

Define $H$ by, for each $x \in G$,

$$H(x)\Big( \displaystyle\sum_{g\in G} a_g \,g \Big) = \displaystyle\sum_{g\in G} a_g \, xg$$

I seek to show that $H$ is a representation. To do so, I need only show that $H$ is a homomorphism, i.e. that $H(xy) = H(x)H(y)$ for all $x,y \in G$. But I appear to be stuck. So far, all I obtain is:

Let $x,y \in G$. Then

$$H(xy) \Big(\displaystyle\sum_{g \in G} a_g g \Big) = \displaystyle\sum_{g \in G}a_g(xy)g$$

$$ = \Big(\displaystyle\sum_{g \in G}a_gxg \Big)y = \Big[ H(x) \Big(\displaystyle\sum_{g \in G} a_g g \Big) \Big] y$$

But beyond this point, I am lost. I can't figure out to pull two summations out of one, which is what I would need to obtain $H(x)H(y)$. Any advice?

Comment: I don't really understand your computations. No that applying composition $H(x)H(y)$ means that we first apply $H(y)$ and then $H(x)$.

Comment: But you mustn't assume $yg=gy$.

Comment: @richrow $xy$ is an element of G. And $H(xy)$ is merely $H$ evaluated at $xy$ as described by the mapping for $H$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're getting confused by what each thing means. The thing you're trying to prove is basically true by definition. Here's the rearrangement you're looking for:
\begin{align*}
H(xy) \sum_{g\in G} a_gg &= \sum_{g\in G} a_g(xyg) 
\\
&= H(x)\sum_{g\in G}a_g(yg)
\\
&= H(x)\Big(H(y)\sum_{g\in G}a_gg\Big)
\\
&= (H(x) \circ H(y))\sum_{g\in G}a_g g.
\end{align*}